# MVC pass list to jQuery and extract elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass a list from my MVC-controller to a javascript in my view.
Here's the method in my controller

```
    private void PopulateChart() {

        var diagramItem = new DiagramPoll();
        var diagramList = new List<DiagramPoll>();
        diagramItem.Color = "#F7464A";
        diagramItem.Label = "System 1";
        diagramItem.Value = "10";
        diagramList.Add(diagramItem);

        diagramItem.Color = "##FDB45C";
        diagramItem.Label = "System 2";
        diagramItem.Value = "20";
        diagramList.Add(diagramItem);

        ViewBag.MyValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(diagramList, Formatting.None);
    }
```

And in the script-section in the view-file:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {             
            var chartValues = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.MyValues);
        //This is what I would like to do:
        foreach (var item in chartValues) {
              var color = item.Color;
              var label = item.Label;
              var value = item.Value
        }
        });
    </script>
```

I need to extract the variables above to send them as input parameters to a jQuery-chart.

Thank you!

Comment: would you get any JavaScript or any other error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For passing values from view to script you need to add it in quotes. Change your script to as below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {             
        var chartValues = '@ViewBag.MyValues';

    });
</script>
```

Also you would not be able to iterate through it, firstly you will need to convert serialized json object to proper json object.

Something like this and then run foreach over json object.

```
var chartData = $.parseJson(chartValues);
foreach (var item in chartData ) {
      var color = item.Color;
      var label = item.Label;
      var value = item.Value
}
```

Or

```
var chartData = JSON.parse(chartValues);
```

but you will have to convert chartValues for sure

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
@model IList<WebApplication2.Models.DiagramPoll>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {             
    //This is what I would like to do:
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        var color = item.Color;
        var label = item.Label;
        var value = item.Value;
    }
});
```

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        var diagramItem = new DiagramPoll();
        var diagramList = new List<DiagramPoll>();
        diagramItem.Color = "#F7464A";
        diagramItem.Label = "System 1";
        diagramItem.Value = "10";
        diagramList.Add(diagramItem);

        diagramItem.Color = "##FDB45C";
        diagramItem.Label = "System 2";
        diagramItem.Value = "20";
        diagramList.Add(diagramItem);

        return View(diagramList);
    }
```